Как лучше создавать списки для функций в python
Есть функция для работы которой нужен список
voted_people = []

async def vote_callback_handler(callback: CallbackQuery, callback_data: NightCallback, bot: Bot):
    if callback.from_user.id not in voted_people:
        voted_people.append(callback.from_user.id)
    if len(voted_people) == len(registration.live_players):
        print("голосование закончилось") 

дальше после отработки функции этот список не нужен будет, а таких функций много и эти списки засоряют код и память. Есть какие то варианты создавать временные списки которые после отработки будут исчезать

Используйте локальные переменные, в чем проблема?

"будут исчезать" del voted_people

@Amgarak то есть внутри функции?

@Flectere да, внутри функции. После того как функция отработает, все объекты внутри неё "исчезнут" (если были объявлены внутри функции).

@Amgarak у меня функция которая вызывается не определенное количество раз и этот список нужен

@Flectere тогда используйте del ‍♀️
